# SIP Invite content-length

Tags: sip

I'm developing a SIP provider application.I use transport UDP.And I have a Questions,
I sending a Invite message SIP Server.

```
INVITE sip:102@192.168.1.33 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.33:5001;branch=z9hG4bK9232c352-a28c-4467-988e-8027e0031209;rport
To: <sip:102@192.168.1.33>
From: "101"<sip:101@192.168.1.33:5060>;tag=rkktjbvq
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Call-ID: lrfnpvlvrbojabxnuldgejvncshccjpwsfxsobpcpmjrnsvkeh
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:101@192.168.1.33:5001>
User-Agent: Iconium
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 849

v=0
o=101 940412967 940412967 IN IP4 192.168.1.33
s=Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.33
t=0 0
m=audio 5003 RTP/AVP 8 0 101 98 9 3 100 97 103 15 4 104 105 106 107 18
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=rtpmap:98 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:98 mode=30
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=fmtp:9 bitrate=64000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:100 SPEEX/16000
a=rtpmap:97 SPEEX/8000
a=rtpmap:103 L16/8000
a=rtpmap:15 G728/8000
a=rtpmap:4 G723/8000
a=rtpmap:104 G726-16/8000
a=rtpmap:105 G726-24/8000
a=rtpmap:106 G726-32/8000
a=rtpmap:107 G726-40/8000
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
a=sendrecv
m=video 5005 RTP/AVP 102 99 34
a=rtpmap:102 H263-1998/90000
a=fmtp:102 QCIF=1;CIF=1
a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
a=fmtp:99 packetization-mode=1
a=rtpmap:34 H263/90000
a=fmtp:34 QCIF=1;CIF=1
a=sendrecv
```

Everything is okay.And SIP Server response with Proxy-Authenticate

```
SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.33:5001;branch=z9hG4bK9232c352-a28c-4467-988e-8027e0031209;rport=5001
Proxy-Authenticate:Digest nonce="414d535c05ab5fd821:79225947c170510b155be0828d92e7e4", algorithm=MD5, realm="3CXPhoneSystem"
To: <sip:102@192.168.1.33>;tag=d92fe85a
From: "101"<sip:101@192.168.1.33:5060>;tag=rkktjbvq
Call-ID: lrfnpvlvrbojabxnuldgejvncshccjpwsfxsobpcpmjrnsvkeh
CSeq: 1 INVITE
User-Agent: 3CXPhoneSystem 10.0.23053.0
Content-Length: 0
```

And I send Authanticate with ACK;

```
INVITE sip:102@192.168.1.33 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.33:5001;branch=z9hG4bKaaf896d5-bd08-48f2-8e3d-0cf043e8324e;rport
To: <sip:102@192.168.1.33>
From: "101"<sip:101@192.168.1.33:5060>;tag=rkktjbvq
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Call-ID: lrfnpvlvrbojabxnuldgejvncshccjpwsfxsobpcpmjrnsvkeh
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:101@192.168.1.33:5001>
User-Agent: Iconium
Content-Type: application/sdp
Proxy-Authorization:Digest username="101", realm="3CXPhoneSystem", nonce="414d535c05ab5fd821:79225947c170510b155be0828d92e7e4", response="8592afb1b7f3440afd9607dc3db588cb", uri="sip:102@192.168.1.33", algorithm=MD5
Content-Length: 849

v=0
o=101 940412967 940412967 IN IP4 192.168.1.33
s=Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.33
t=0 0
m=audio 5003 RTP/AVP 8 0 101 98 9 3 100 97 103 15 4 104 105 106 107 18
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=rtpmap:98 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:98 mode=30
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=fmtp:9 bitrate=64000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:100 SPEEX/16000
a=rtpmap:97 SPEEX/8000
a=rtpmap:103 L16/8000
a=rtpmap:15 G728/8000
a=rtpmap:4 G723/8000
a=rtpmap:104 G726-16/8000
a=rtpmap:105 G726-24/8000
a=rtpmap:106 G726-32/8000
a=rtpmap:107 G726-40/8000
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
a=sendrecv
m=video 5005 RTP/AVP 102 99 34
a=rtpmap:102 H263-1998/90000
a=fmtp:102 QCIF=1;CIF=1
a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
a=fmtp:99 packetization-mode=1
a=rtpmap:34 H263/90000
a=fmtp:34 QCIF=1;CIF=1
a=sendrecv
```

And Sıp server response with

```
SIP 2.0/400 Bad Content-Length(larger than datagram)
```

But in Ozeki Voip SDK , 
while content-length=851 everything is okay.(using UDP transport)

How can I do for this?Where is the my problem?

**Edit:**
My UDP client:

```
 private void SendSIPMessage(string mesaj, bool korumalı)
        {

            IPEndPoint remotendpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
            try
            {
                udpClient.Connect("192.168.1.33", 5060);
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mesaj);
                udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
                string receivedMessage = string.Empty;
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref remotendpoint);
                receivedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
                label1.Text += receivedMessage + "\n";

        }
```

Comment: If you view the messages sent over the network through something like Wireshark, what do you see? Is your UDP datagram fragmenting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply the server might have a setting to reject too large UDP packets.
I would suggest to remove some codecs from your software. Your list is too large and I don't think that it has any reason.

Answer (score 4):

It might be because your UDP SIP packet is over MTU or 1300 bytes.

RFC 3261 - 18.1.1 Sending Requests

> If a request is within 200 bytes of the path MTU, or if it is larger
>   than 1300 bytes and the path MTU is unknown, the request MUST be sent
>   using an RFC 2914 [43] congestion controlled transport protocol, such
>   as TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Most SIP proxies would accept that size of message over UDP no problem. You might want to try a different SIP server. In production systems, it is fairly normal for the SIP message to get larger than a single MTU but this still work when the UDP packets gets fragmented into two parts.